# NoSuchMethodException while parsing on Apache Nutch

Tags: apache-commons, nutch, apache-tika, apache-commons-compress

I am crawling using Apache Nutch 1.13 . During parse step I am getting this error. I am not able to produce the url leading to this error

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorStreamFactory.<init>(Z)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.CompressorStreamFactory.<init>(Z)V
        at org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.CompressorParser.parse(CompressorParser.java:120)
        at org.apache.nutch.parse.tika.TikaParser.getParse(TikaParser.java:134)
        at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseUtil.parse(ParseUtil.java:107)
        at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment.map(ParseSegment.java:109)
        at org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseSegment.map(ParseSegment.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I traced the logs but I couldn't understand the issue. Any help will b appreciated!!

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of Commons Compress on your classpath. How did you get the jars, manually or with something like maven?

Comment: Nutch 1.14 fixed an issue ([NUTCH-2378](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2378)) - core library dependencies where prioritized over plugin dependencies.

Comment: @Gagravarr I went to the maven website and grabed it.

Comment: @SebastianNagel I patched the issue, I found some redundant code in Apache Tika, at org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.CompressorParser.parse(CompressorParser.java:120), I just removed the boolean argument as It had same functionality even without it. Compiled it and used it.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianNagel, I missed that issue when I was wandering in Nutch Issue Tracker. will add this patch to Nutch :D